# Converting Date String to ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, spring-boot, zoneddatetime, java-calendar

I'm receiving a **query parameter** date, as `yyyy-MM-DD (2022-03-08)`.
I want to conver this to `java.util.Calendar` / `java.util.GregorianCalendar` formmat.

So my idea is converto:
String -> ZonedDateTime -> Calendar.

What I did:

```
ZonedDateTime parsedDate = ZonedDateTime.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
//date = 2022-03-08
```

even with the correct format, I'm getting:

```
Text '2022-03-08' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 2022-03-08 of type java.time.format.Parsed
```

I found out that this error occurs because my string does not have a TimeZone.

One suggestion was to use `LocalDate`

```
 DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
 LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(fecha, formatter);
```

but I can't use `localDate` as an argument for `ZonedDateTime.parse()`.

What else could I try?

Comment: Do dates have a concept of timezone?  Seems counterintuitive to me (but I'm an idiot), but it probably explains where there's no such thing as `ZonedDate` :/

Comment: *"I want to conver this to java.util.Calendar / java.util.GregorianCalendar formmat"* - no, no you don't.  Keep it within the `java.time` API

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to conver this to java.util.Calendar / java.util.GregorianCalendar formmat.

That seems silly; Calendar/GregorianCalendar is obsolete, and the API is **horrendous**. Why use a broken screwdriver when there's a shiny new one right there in the toolbox? Don't do this.

> So my idea is converto: String -> ZonedDateTime -> Calendar.

That seems silly. The string does not contain a `ZonedDateTime`. It doesn't even contain a `LocalDateTime`. It is clearly a `LocalDate`. So, convert it to a localdate, and you go from there.

The power of the `java.time` package is that each different concept in time has a matching type in the j.t package that is properly named. For example, `java.util.Date` is a lie: It is a timestamp, and it has nothing whatsoever to do with dates; asking a Date object for 'what year is it', is broken (try it, you get a warning).

Calendar, similarly, is an utter falsehood. It does not represent a calendar at all; it, too, represents a timestamp.

`LocalDate` on the other hand is perfect truth: It represents a date (not a time), and it does not include timezone or other localizing information: It makes sense only as 'locally'.

Each stop should just make sense, on its own:

```java
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd");
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2022-10-01", formatter);
```

So far, so good. I'd just stop there - why lie? Why return a Calendar which is both API wise a lie (that class does not represent calendars), and even if someone knows exactly what Calendar is, it's *still* a lie: A calendar implies it has exact time *and* a timezone. You do *not* have a time, and also don't have a timezone. Why return something that suggests stuff that isn't there?

But, if you MUST, then explicitly add a timezone and a time, and THEN go for it:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = someLocalDate.atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Amsterdam"));
GregorianCalendar gc = GregorianCalendar.from(zdt);
```

This code is clear and legible: It makes crystal clear that the code picks a time, and picks a zone.

But, again, now you ended up with a horrible, horrible object you should not be using, for anything.

Comment: Beautiful explanation. Thank you so much for this! The reason I'm aiming specific `Calendar`, is because I'm working with a legacy code, and its already using Calendar.

Answer (score 3):

There are other ways of getting a `ZonedDateTime` than just its static `parse()` method.  Here's how to turn a `LocalDateTime` into a `ZonedDateTime`:

```
ZonedDateTime zoned = dateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of( "America/New_York"));
```

or if you have a `LocalDate`:

```
ZonedDateTime zoned = 
          date.atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ));
```

I would not use `java.util.Calendar` or `Date`.  They're junk.  I'd either stick with `LocalDate` or use `ZonedDateTime` depending on if you need to keep track of time zones or not. This should get you where you want to go either way, I guess, as it sounds like you know what you want to do once you have a `ZonedDateTime`.

UPDATE:  I looked up how to convert a ZoneDateTime to a Calendar:

```
Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.from(zoned);
```

just in case you hadn't gotten that far and really want to go that way.